# Angular2 input accept only number when typing, but not doing the same while doing copy paste

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

I have created an input field like as shown below in Angular2 which should accept only numbers.

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="streetCode" ngModel [maxlength]="2" (keypress)="onlyNumber($event)">
```

**typescipt**

```
onlyNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above code is working fine and allows only number from keyboard, but the issue is that when I do copy paste of some alphabet character onto to the input field it is allowing alphabets.

**Update 1:**
Actually when I say copy paste, its through mouse copy paste and not through keyboard.

Can anyone please help me on this

**Update 2**

Right now I have modified the code as shown below, Don't know whether this is a right approach:

```
  onlyNumber(evt) {
    if (evt.type === 'paste') {
      let content = evt.clipboardData.getData('Text');
      if (isNaN(content)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="streetCode" ngModel [maxlength]="2" (keypress)="onlyNumber($event)" (paste)="onlyNumber($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use type="number" instead of text. In that case you don't need the keypress event. It is a pure html syntax.

Comment: Can you take a look at my Update2

Comment: I have seen your changes.
1. Try 'input' event  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myValue" (change)="onlyNumber($event)" />

Comment: I have seen your changes.You could try something like this.
1. Try 'input' event  <input type="text" name="myValue" [(ngModel)]="myValue" (input)="onlyNumber($event)" />

function onlyNumber(evt){
var value = evt.target.value;
    try {
        if(typeof value !== 'number' || isNaN(value)){
          throw 'Not a number';
        }
        value = parseFloat(value);

    } catch (exception) {
        console.error(exception);
        value = '';
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the `keydown` and `keyup` events represent keys being pressed or released, while the `keypress` event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

So I guess the suggestion is to use `keydown/keyup` events instead of `keypress` if you want to also listen paste event if you don't want to use
`type="number"` instead of text.

Comment: @fatemefazil Thanks for the reply...may be I have not conveyed my issue properly....actualy when I say copy paste....I mean through mouse copy paste...

Comment: @fatemefazil Can you take a look at my Update2

Comment: @AlexMan it's ok if it works, did you try using ```keydown``` and ```keyup``` ?

Comment: I have added `keydown` and `keyup`

Comment: you are right key up down wont trigger mouse event, your code is ok, you can write this way too:  ```(keypress , paste)="onlyNumber($event)" ```

Answer (score 0):

Your function onlyNumber will  get triggered  only on keypress event 
That's the reason why it's not working on copy paste

Try using ngModelChange instead of keypress

Comment: i checked the update but what i had in mind was <input [ngModel] ="userInputValue" (ngModelChange) ="onlyNumber($event)"/> and inside function onlyNumber have the checks for number and assign it to userInputValue

Comment: Can you take a look at my Update2